# Deleting URL from database

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, wxwidgets

I have database that contains URL as Primary Key.
The table  schema is

```
 -- Describe HISTORY
CREATE TABLE history  ("name" TEXT NOT NULL,  "location"  TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "time_date" DATE)
```

and sample data

```
|   name    |   location                            |   time_date   |
|   Google  |   http://www.google.co.tz/?gws_rd=cr  |   2013-08-13  |
```

So I do:

```
DELETE FROM history WHERE location="http://www.google.co.tz/?gws_rd=cr"
```

But delete does not work! If I delete by date or delete everything it works fine so it seems that I need some sort of escaping URL. I use wxSQLite3 with function below

```
DeleteHistory(const wxString& location)
{
    wxString sql = wxT("DELETE FROM history WHERE location=?;");
    try
    {
        wxSQLite3Statement stmt = m_db->PrepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.Bind(1, location);

        stmt.ExecuteUpdate();
        stmt.Reset();
        stmt.Finalize();//done
    }
    catch (wxSQLite3Exception& e)
    {
        wxMessageBox(e.GetMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Database file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/szori418cryvvuy/browser.config

What am I missing?

Comment: You're sure there's no trailing spaces in the `location` string in the db? Are there any other tables referencing that specific entry?

Comment: Not sure because all I do is I set string programatically and I load same string in wxListCtrl and I use again the same string to send Query. So I believe it should not make any difference, should it?

Comment: I tested your code by adding it to the minimal sample coming with wxSQLite3. It worked as expected - although calling Reset and Finalize for the prepared statement is not necessary. That is, the corresponding entry was deleted.

Maybe something goes wrong when you insert the data. Could you provide the resulting database for further inspection?

Comment: @UlrichTelle Database file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/szori418cryvvuy/browser.config

Comment: Stefano, I downloaded the database file and took a look. From what I see I think you are saving your data in the wrong column sequence. You find the "location" value (i.e. "http://...") in the "name" column and vice versa. So it's not surprising that your DELETE command doesn't work. You could change the WHERE condition to "WHERE name=?". However, it would be certainly better to check your code you are using for saving and retrieving data to/from your table and correct the sequence of the column values.

Comment: you are right! I wonder why I was not seeing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dumb in that I exchanged the arguments during Inserting data in the database so the delete could not work (since where clause pointed to wrong data that aren't in the referred column). In short, I was exchanging columns values during insert (i.e inserting url in name and vice versa).

I rectified the code and its working, thanks to Ulrich Telle for pointing out as I quote him

> Stefano, I downloaded the database file and took a look. From what I
>   see I think you are saving your data in the wrong column sequence. You
>   find the "location" value (i.e. "http://...") in the "name" column and
>   vice versa. So it's not surprising that your DELETE command doesn't
>   work. You could change the WHERE condition to "WHERE name=?". However,
>   it would be certainly better to check your code you are using for
>   saving and retrieving data to/from your table and correct the sequence
>   of the column values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to put the location parameter in quotes, since it contains (or could contain) a question mark (interpreted as a placeholder).

Comment: The Comment in Link below says it is not necessary (BTW Adding that to place holder makes it string literal throwing same error in the link)
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/44144

Comment: I have done some test, it does not even delete those without ?

Comment: can you run in debug mode, and look at the value of 'location' before the sql call is made ?

Comment: When parameter binding is used (as is the case here), no quoting or escaping is required. 
Without seeing the complete code and the database it's only wild guessing. However, there has to be a difference between the string in the application and the string residing in the database file - maybe just some whitespace -, because I tested the code myself and deleting worked when the strings were equal.

Comment: I will try to trim both of spaces and see if it works. Also updated the post with sample database.